# mysql statement for getting data from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

i have 3 tables for a quiz

`cursos`(quizes) that has an id as PK

`preguntas_cursos` (questions) that has an id as PK and has an id_curso as FK thats the same as the id in cursos (previous table)

and theres a third table for the answers `opciones_preguntas_cursos` that has an id as PK and a FK `preguntas_cursos_id` that's the same as `preguntas_cursos_id` (previous table)

i want to join this 3 together:

here's the statement i am trying:

```
SELECT cursos.nombre_curso, pc.curso_id, pc.id AS preg_id, pc.pregunta, opc.id AS resp_id, opc.respuesta, opc.es_correcta 
FROM preguntas_cursos AS pc, opciones_preguntas_cursos AS opc, cursos
WHERE pc.id = opc.preguntas_cursos_id
AND cursos.id = pc.curso_id
```

but this query is just giving me a set of rows with only one id of `cursos`, its not showing them all

what am i doing wrong, or whats the best way to accomplish what i am trying to do???

Comment: can you please build your tables with data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and post the URL? thanks

Comment: You want to join to retrieve what information?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the join in the where, you should do it int he from and it should be a left join.

```
SELECT cursos.nombre_curso, pc.curso_id, pc.id AS preg_id, pc.pregunta, opc.id AS resp_id, opc.respuesta, opc.es_correcta 
FROM preguntas_cursos AS pc LEFT JOIN (opciones_preguntas_cursos AS opc,cursos) ON (pc.id = opc.preguntas_cursos_id AND cursos.id = pc.curso_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to build your [table schema on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9d35/10). It's bearly an assumption looking at some info, query in your question. [Correct me if I am wrong). How do you choose which JOIN to use in your case? You are saying you want to get all the records corresponding to cursos IDs. You want to return only the selective records which are **common in the tables on basis of common columns**. Left join just does that. When you add the refrential integrity to your table schema by defining the foreign keys by each table's primary key - you created that common columns/the reference.

I have put a solution query and its output for you in the same SQLFiddle for you get a clear idea. If LEFT JOIN wasn't avaiable, you would have to run few selects, inner join, unions within your query. So it saves lots of hassel.

```
SELECT c.id, c.quiz_name,
        p.cursos_id, p.question,
        o.id,o.answers 
FROM preguntas_cursos p
LEFT JOIN
        (opciones_preguntas_cursos o, cursos c)
ON (p.id = o.preg_id
AND c.id = p.cursos_id)
```

- Here is one [Great post on JOINS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-full-join-in-mys)